# Extract string URL from file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file called `remoteEntry.js`

And there is something like this in the file:

`var remotes = {"home":"http://localhost:3001/_next/static/ssr/remoteEntry.js"};`

And I want to extract `http://localhost:3001` from the above

It could be http or https sometimes

How to do it in shell script?

Tried this but doesn't work

`$(echo "$line" | grep -Eo 'http://[^_next]+' | head -1)`

Comment: You can try with `grep`

Comment: `grep -Eo 'http.*'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -Eo 'https?://[^/]+' file
http://localhost:3001
```

The bracket expression you used, `[^_next]` means "any character except `_`, `n`, `e`, `x`, or `t`" which is why the output stops just before the first `t` in the input after `http://`:

```
$ grep -Eo 'http://[^_next]+' file
http://localhos
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
var remotes = {"home":"http://localhost:3001/_next/static/ssr/remoteEntry.js"};
```